# Read Specific values from given address?

Tags: c

Given the 16 bit address(memory address, not value) 0x1144, 16-bit is divided into Type bit 15- bit 16 , Module bit 9 to bit 14, group bit 1 to bit 8

Type = Bit 15 - Bit 16

Module = Bit 9 - Bit 14

Group = Bit 1 - Bit 8

Read and Print the Values in Following variables.

```
uint16_t Type;
uint16_t Module;
uint16_t Group;
```

How to read & print values using C.

I tried with

```
uint16_t *ptr = 0x1144;
Type = *ptr >> 14;
Module = *ptr << 2;
Module = Module >> 10;
Group = *ptr << 8;
Group = Group >> 8;
```

Is this the correct ?

Comment: What does this mean? What do networks have to do with memory addresses?

Comment: @Barmar, it just example , nothing to do with network.

Comment: What problem are you having? Just initialize a pointer variable to `0x1144` and then dereference it.

Comment: Dereference pointer will give me all the 16 bits .

Comment: Do you know how to get the bits you want from an ordinary `unsigned int` variable? Do the same thing with the dereferenced pointer.

Comment: pointer with uint16_t type and using bitwise shifting ?

Comment: @Barmar i Updated Question with what i tried ?

Comment: @PankajSuryawanshi, what do you mean by "How to read & print values using C"? Your code gets the job done in one way. What else do you want?

Comment: @kuro, did u mean what i tried is correct ? if correct any other way ?

Comment: I am pretty sure you've misunderstood the question entirely, and the network address means that the number **0x1144** **is** the 16-bit network address, not an address of a variable.

Comment: The question doesn't say anything about dereferencing the address. The "16-bit" to be decomposed could be the "16 bit address" itself, and I would consider that the most reasonable interpretation. If the interviewer expects you to dereference the address, that would be a very unfair question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Bit fields in C which is quite commonly used while addressing individual bit positions in HW registers. Just model your bit positions in a `struct` by defining below (on my machine with little endian)

```
typedef struct {
    uint16_t group:8;
    uint16_t module:6;
    uint16_t type:2;
}nwGroup ;
```

All you need to do is cast the address containing your 16 bit value to this `struct` type and you can access the fields individually after that.

```
uint16_t *val = (uint16_t *)0x1144;
nwGroup  *ptr = (nwGroup*)(val);
printf("NW group: %d\n", ptr->group);
```

Comment: This is actually the solution I wish I'd thought of first. ;-) Well done. But, one should also learn about bitwise manipulation, so I'll leave my lousy answer there for a while.

Comment: @PankajSuryawanshi Does what you tried give you consistently correct results?

Comment: @PankajSuryawanshi: It depends on how frequent you are doing this read. If its too often recommend using bit fields like this and getting the values.

Comment: This has a strict aliasing violation, possible aliasing violation, use of `uint16_t` in a bitfield is implementation-defined and the bitfield layout is implementation-defined. If it works then it works, maybe.

Comment: And converting an integer to a pointer requires an explicit cast.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: Would a explicit cast as `(uint16_t *)(uintptr_t)0x1144 ` is what you suggest

Comment: explicit cast `(uint16_t *)0x1144` would be sufficient, perhaps. But then again, this is an interview question so we must assume that OP has misunderstood it completely.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: Made the edit for the explicit cast and agree on the strict aliasing violation. Possibly revert the downvote, if you feel the answer is better

Comment: Specifying the machine as "little-endian" is insufficient for determining the position of bit-fields within an allocation unit. That needs to be specified as well.

Comment: @IanAbbott: Can you explain a bit more on what I need to specify? I did not get it from your last comment .I will correct it in my answer

Comment: @Inian Here are some references from C11 for the implementation-defined parts. 6.2.6.1 para. 2 covers byte ordering except for bit-fields ("little-endian" would be part of the implementation-specification). 6.7.2.1 para. 11 covers the order of allocation of bit-fields (which is implementation-specified). 6.7.2.1 para. 5 covers the types allowed for bit-fields - anything other than `_Bool`, `signed int` or `unsigned int` is implementation-specified.

Answer (score 1):

(Note: We usually number things starting from 0 in computer science, so I've interpreted your requirements from a zero-based mindset.)

Use a combination of masking and shifting. For example, if you want to be able to recover the NetworkModule value, create a mask that has 1-bits in the positions you want, and 0-bits everywhere else:

```
#define NetworkModuleMask 0x3E00  // that is, 0011 1110 0000 0000
```

Now you can use that to mask out the unwanted bits using bitwise AND:

```
int address = 0x1144;
int networkModule = address & NetworkModuleMask
```

Another way to do it, which is essentially equivalent, is to use division and modulo operators with powers of 2. For example, your NetworkGroup is the

Then, to interpret the value as a number, you'll want to shift it right by 9 bits:

```
#define NetworkModulePosition 9
networkModule = networkModule >> NetworkModulePosition
```

You can use a similar process to construct an address using component values: shift each part into position and then bitwise OR it into the address.

You can also approach the problem arithmetically, using division and modulo operators with powers of 2. Dividing an integer by a power of 2 is the same as shifting it to the right by some number of bits, and modulo by a power of 2 is the same as shifting some number of bits to the right and then clearing some number of bits on the left, so you end up doing pretty much what we did above. For example, your `NetworkGroup` value is the low 8 bits of the address, so you can recover it by taking the address mod 2^^8, or 256. The `NetworkType` is the highest 2 bits, and you can recover that by dividing the address by 2^^14, or 16384.

Comment: How ? please explain in brief.

Comment: Sorry -- I hit the submit button before I was done typing. Hope the answer in its current form is illustrative; this is a pretty common thing to do in C.

Comment: int address = 0x1144, its address not value and you are assigning it to the normal variable ?

Comment: I have mention its 16 bit, but in your answer int is 32-bit ?

Comment: @PankajSuryawanshi Yes, I was treating 0x1144 as the value -- I thought you were referring to some sort of network address, not a memory address. I'd suggest that you first figure this out using plain integers before you move on to pointers.

Comment: In c it is not possible to use address without pointer ?, pointer is required as per the problem statement ?

Comment: @PankajSuryawanshi Where is there a 32-bit value? 4 hex digits make 16 bits.

Comment: int variable is 32 bit.

Comment: @PankajSuryawanshi If 0x1144 is a pointer to the value that you're trying to interpret, then just get the value at that address and do what I suggested above. That is, `uint16 value = *address;` and then manipulate the bits in `value` as I've explained above. And btw, the size of an `int` depends on your environment; if you've got a system with 16-bit pointers like `0x1144`, then you likely also have 16-bit ints.